# Tough Subgroup problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, and $S \subseteq G$ a subset. Define subsets of $G$ by putting $T_0=\{e\}$, $T_1=\{x\in G | {x\in S} \ \text{or} \ {x^{-1} \in S\}}$, and for $n>1$, let 
$T_n=\{xy| x\in T_{n-1} \ \text{and} \ y\in T_1\}.$

($a$) Prove by induction on $n$, that if $g\in T_m$ and $h\in T_n$, then $gh \in T_{m+n}$.

($b$) Prove that if $g\in T_n$, then $g^{-1}\in T_n.$

($c$) Let $T = \cup_{n=0}^\infty T_n$. Prove that $T$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $T=<S>$, the subgroup generated by $S$.

I have no idea how to even start this problem, any solutions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $T_n \subset T_{n+1}$ for all $n$.

Comment: Hint 2 : $T_n = \{ x_1 \cdots x_n : x_1, \ldots, x_n \in T_1 \}$.

Comment: This is too hard to read. Please proofread and edit!

Comment: @polmath: It is not necessarily true that $T_n \subset T_{n+1}$. Rather, it is true that $e \in T_2$ and hence $T_n \subset T_{n+2}$. For a counterexample to the first statement, take $S = \{g\}$ for some $g \neq e$.

Comment: @PedroMilet: you are right, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In fact we have that $T_1=S \cup S^{-1}$ and so $T_2=T_1T_1=(S \cup S^{-1})^2$, $T_3=T_2T_1=(S \cup S^{-1})^3$,$\ldots$,$T_n=(S \cup S^{-1})^n$.
 This shows how for a) we have $T_nT_m=(S \cup S^{-1})^m(S \cup S^{-1})^n=(S \cup S^{-1})^{m+n}=T_{n+m}$.
For b) we have $T_n^{-1}=(S \cup S^{-1})^{-n}=((S \cup S^{-1})^{-1})^n=(S ^{-1}\cup S)^n=T_n$.
From a) and b) we may conclude that $T$ is a group because if $g,h\in T$ then $g\in T_n$ for some $n$ and $h^{-1}\in T_m$ for some $m$ so $gh^{-1}\in T_{n+m} \subset T$. Since $S \subset T$ and $<S>$ is the smallest group containing $S$ we have $<S> \subset T$. Let $t\in T$ then, by definition $t=t_1t_2\ldots t_n$ for some $n$ and $t_k\in S \cup S^{-1}$. This shows that $t \in <S>$ so $T\subset<S>$.